# Find an egf for $\sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

The egf would be $\sum_{n = 0} [\sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k}]\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ = $\sum_{n = 0} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ = $\sum_{n = 0} \frac{x^{n}}{k!(n-k)!}$

From here I'm a little stuck, can someone direct me to some formulas that seem to be eluding me?

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$ has a very simple closed form.

Comment: Isn't there no closed formula for a partial sum of binomial coefficients?

Comment: Where's the partial sum? You've got the complete sum.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k} = (x+y)^n$. Choose $x$ and $y$ suitably :)

Comment: So would I move the $x^{n}$ inside?  It's a partial sum because it goes to a certain value of $n$ not to infinity right? Or am I understanding this wrong... What would x, y be in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know the *[exponential generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function)* of $e^x$ is
\begin{align*}
  e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
  \end{align*}

> Since $e^{2x}=e^xe^x$, we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> e^{2x}=e^xe^x&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{x^l}{l!}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{x^n}{k!l!}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{n!}{k!l!}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Many thanks for pointing to this mystery! :-) Typo corrected.